# PostScript Printer loading

Tags: performance, printing, postscript

We have a VarioPrint 135 laser printer. Printer has ability to print via Postscript. I was trying to set some properties which could lead to print out immediately. But with no luck.
I was trying to print 10000 A4, but the printer is spooling everytime (even if i set print directly to printer). It's not possible to wait more than one hour for spooling.
I am able to print via PCL driver, but we couldn't do that because there is no   full bleed option. But when the printer starts spool some files it starts printing.
I expect same behaviour when I am using PostScript driver.
Any ideas?